# Can one someone have a roommate light Shabbat candles for them

Tags: halacha, shabbat, candle-lighting, petur-exemption, orach-chaim

If a Jewish person shares a dorm or apartment with another Jewish person and the other person lights Shabbat candles, are they covered by that lighting or no? In this case they are not related nor are they romantic partners.

According to Halacha, is it required of  them as an individual to light or can they have a roommate/dorm mate do it for them? Sources for the answer to this question are appreciated please.

Comment: They're all obligated, but one person can light on behalf of everyone.

Comment: Isn't this what nearly everyone does every week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that there is not much of a difference between two roommates/ apartment mates and a standard family. The same way a mother can light for her family I would presume roommates to be the same, that one can light for each.

When a single individual lives in the house of another family it is preferable for the individual to buy into the lighting of the household.

When two people share in the ownership of their apartment I would venture to say that it is considered a household and one may light for the both of them.

I will try to get sources